# ASP.NET Substring cutting off sentence

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a paragraph of text that I get from a database, I only want the first 175 characters, which I am able to get via this:

```
@item.post.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.post.Length, 175))
```

However, it cuts off my paragraph, is it possible to get grab the paragraph unto 175 characters, however don’t grab anything after the last period so my paragraph looks like this…

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nunc metus, varius vel mi eu, sagittis hendrerit sem. Sed sit amet lectus in eros vulputate lacinia.

instead of this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nunc metus, varius vel mi eu, sagittis hendrerit sem. Sed sit amet lectus in eros vulputate lacinia. Vestibulum

I guess my question is, after I get the first 175 characters, how would I grab the text to the last period?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes, of course it is.  Does the framework do this by itself?  No.  You would have to come up with the algorithm and write it.  By the way, that's a sentence, not a paragraph.  You should first figure out the exact situation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@item.post.Substring(0, @item.post.Substring(0, 175).LastIndexOf('.')+1);
```

Though this will fail if the sentence doesn't contain any periods, so you may want to do some tweaking before using it. (checking that the period exists)

Comment: This also won't look right for sentences such as, `(Some unrelated sentence.)`, as it will cut off the `)`.

Comment: Exactly, a better solution I think would be to actually separate down to the last space character and append three periods so that we end up with something like this instead `Lorem ipsum blablabla. Vestibulum...` or even.. `Vestibulum (read more...)`